# Publish sites at custom portnumbers in windows azure?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, ports

We are trying to publish three sites in Azure, they are on ports 8080-8082.
The site on 8080 works fine, the sites on 8081 and 8082 does however not respond from the outside.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is on a single role, right?  Can you put your ServiceDefinition up to look at?  Typically this is because you miconfigured input endpoints or the binding.  Here is a trivial example that has 3 sites on 3 different ports.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="WindowsAzureProject1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="MvcWebRole1">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web1" physicalDirectory="../pathtowebsite1">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="Web2" physicalDirectory="../pathtowebsite2">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="Web2" physicalDirectory="../pathtowebsite3">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint3" endpointName="Endpoint3" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8080" />
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="http" port="8081" />
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint3" protocol="http" port="8082" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```